# How to infer number of function args based on array length

Tags: typescript

I have a function `nodeId` that I am trying to pass params to by spreading an array. `nodeId` takes two args and I do a check to ensure it has a length of 2 before passing it in but I still get the error:

```
Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more. (2556)
input.tsx(6, 17): An argument for 'long' was not provided.
```

From my code, I don't understand why TS still thinks it is possible for the function to be passed 0 args.

```
const point: number[] = []

point.push(1)
point.push(2)

const nodeId = (long: number, lat: number) => `${long}-${lat}`;

point.length === 2 && nodeId(...point)
```

I could pull each param out but it feels like I should be able to use the spread operator to do this but TS doesn't understand it. Does anyone know if TS is smart enough to infer this from my check or know of a clean way to do the same thing?

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate but I'm not sure if the other question provides an answer to this.  The problem is that mutating methods like `push()` don't change the apparent type of the variable `point`; it stays `number[]`.  If you want to spread it, you need the compiler to know that `point` is a two-element tuple, which can happen like [this](https://tsplay.dev/PmLGkN) if you make the array immutable and initialize it via `const` assertion.  Does that help?